# parse to add string to head and foot

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to python and wanted to parse a text.I joined here because of the reason to solve this parse.Consider I have a sample text file "s1.txt" contains

Sample s1.text

```
I like to play all games and sports
Game=chess
Sports=Baseball
I also like to play other games 
Game=carrom
Sports=cricket
Game=tennis
```

Sample Desired Output:

```
Game=chess
Game=carrom
Game=tennis
I like to play all games and sports
I also like to play other games 
Sports=Baseball
Sports=cricket
```

I get some suggestions to use regex `(.*?)=(.*)`.But regex making confused and is there a better way to solve it using string operations!
Please help me to get the desired output!Answers are appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify how you want the output to be. Is it just alphabetical order?

Comment: Is the output sorted alphabetically?

Comment: no no its not sorted alphabetically!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function which determines the relative value of a particular line. Lines starting with "Game=" have a lower value than usual, and lines starting with "Sports=" have a higher value. Use this function as the key when sorting the collection of lines.

```
def value(line):
    if line.startswith("Game="):
        return 0
    elif line.startswith("Sports="):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1


text = """I like to play all games and sports
Game=chess
Sports=Baseball
I also like to play other games 
Game=carrom
Sports=cricket
Game=tennis"""

lines = text.split("\n")
lines.sort(key=value)
print "\n".join(lines)
```

Result:

```
Game=chess
Game=carrom
Game=tennis
I like to play all games and sports
I also like to play other games
Sports=Baseball
Sports=cricket
```

Comment: Clever. Clever indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want a sort based on a) match of the element on the LH of the the `=` based on an order that you define; b) line order in the file.

Expanding on your example, suppose you have:

```
txt='''\
Pleasure=swimming
I like to play all games and sports
Game=chess
Sports=Baseball
I also like to play other games 
Game=carrom
Sports=cricket
Game=tennis
Pleasure=eating'''
```

If you want to use a regex, you can use Kevin's sort method with the rank of the `re.groups()` object returned to decorate the sort function.

Recall that a regex with multiple match groups will return which match group matched with `None` for the others:

```
>>> re.search(r'(^Game=)|(^Sports=)|(^Pleasure=)', 'Sports=').groups()
(None, 'Sports=', None)
```

Which you can then determine the order of the match group with a generator:

```
>>> next(i for i, e in enumerate((None, 'Sports=', None)) if e)
1
```

Now write a key function for sort:

```
def kf(s, rank_of_none=1):
    m=re.search(r'(^Game=)|(^Sports=)|(^Pleasure=)', s)
    if m:
        return next(i for i, e in enumerate(m.groups()) if e)
    else:
        return rank_of_none-.1
```

Now see that you are adding an integer at the start of a tuple to determine the rank of the sort. We can use a float for no match so that it will sort in line order of the file:

```
for line in txt.splitlines():
    print kf(line), line
```

Output:

```
2 Pleasure=swimming
0.9 I like to play all games and sports
0 Game=chess
1 Sports=Baseball
0.9 I also like to play other games 
0 Game=carrom
1 Sports=cricket
0 Game=tennis
2 Pleasure=eating
```

It is now completely trivial to produce a flexible sort based on the position of the match group in the regex:

```
print '\n'.join(sorted(txt.splitlines(), key=kf))
```

Output:

```
Game=chess
Game=carrom
Game=tennis
I like to play all games and sports
I also like to play other games 
Sports=Baseball
Sports=cricket
Pleasure=swimming
Pleasure=eating
```